# PyQT6 возвращение оригинальный геометрии объектов из Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

После создания в *Qt Designer*  интерфейса, точнее его заготовку, по рекомендации идет создание нового класса и уже работа в нем, что бы не трогать оригинальный код. Но вот в чем вопрос, а как перенести все настройки которые были заданы изначально. Я добавляю те же объекты, но они не наследуют геометрию.

Пробовал переносить настройки, но они не применяются. Я подозреваю, что из-за того, что не сохранена геометрия основного окна.

Каким образом переносить все настройки в новый класс?

Пример моего кода:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QFont


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(693, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.MainComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.MainComboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.MainComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.MainComboBox.setObjectName("MainComboBox")
        self.OfComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.OfComboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.OfComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.OfComboBox.setObjectName("OfComboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 80, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 152, 681, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 152, 681, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label2.setFont(font)
        self.label2.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "TestComboBox"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Choice"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.setupUi(self)

    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

    layout.addWidget(self.label)

    # add button
    layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.copyToClipboard)

    self.model = QStandardItemModel()

    # add ComboBox
    self.MainComboBox.setFixedSize(210, 40)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.MainComboBox.setFont(font)
    self.MainComboBox.setObjectName("MainComboBox")
    self.MainComboBox.setModel(self.model)

    self.OfComboBox.setFixedSize(210, 40)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.OfComboBox.setFont(font)
    self.OfComboBox.setObjectName("OfComboBox")
    self.OfComboBox.setModel(self.model)

    # add data
    for k, v in data.items():
        state = QStandardItem(k)
        self.model.appendRow(state)
        for value in v:
            city = QStandardItem(value)
            state.appendRow(city)

    self.MainComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateItemCombo)
    self.MainComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.description_teg)
    self.OfComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.item_label)
    self.updateItemCombo(0)

    # add ComboBox in Wiget
    layout.addWidget(self.MainComboBox)
    layout.addWidget(self.label2)
    layout.addWidget(self.OfComboBox)
    self.setLayout(layout)

def updateItemCombo(self, index):
    indx = self.model.index(index, 0, self.MainComboBox.rootModelIndex())
    self.OfComboBox.setRootModelIndex(indx)
    self.OfComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)

def item_label(self):
    text_label = self.MainComboBox.currentText()
    text_label2 = self.OfComboBox.currentText()
    self.label.setText(text_label + ' ' + text_label2)

def copyToClipboard(self):
    cb = QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard()
    cb.clear()
    cb.setText(self.label.text())

def description_teg(self, index):
    if index == 1:
        self.label2.setText('Описание: ' + description_date[0])
    if index == 2:
        self.label2.setText(description_date[1])
    if index == 3:
        self.label2.setText(description_date[2])

data = { 'item 0': '',
    'item 1':
        ['item 1.1',
         'item 1.2',
         'item 1.3'],
    'item 2': ['item 2.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.3'],
    'item 3': ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.3']
}

description_date = \
    ['item 1',
     'item 2',
     'item 3']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать и покажите на изображении результат того, что вы хотите получить. Вы хотите использовать менеджеры компоновки? и почему вы их не использовали в Qt Designer ?  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-layouts.html

Comment: К моему сожалению, я не знал про это. Спасибо! Пойду изучать дальше вопрос.